# How to compare lists and get total matching items count

Tags: django, django-views

**Garage.cars:** object garage has a **FK** of cars

**Person.carwishlst:** object Person has **FK** of cars they would like.

In Django how to I achieve the following, loop?...

Get the total number of cars **x** the Person has which match the ones the Garage has.

Outcome:
**i.e. Grange has 4 cars you want**

Hypothetical, but lets say Grange model has an FK cars = models.ManyToManyField(Cars)

Person also has a FK cars_wishlist = models.ManyToManyField(Cars)

Comment: You should use `set()` : http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `cars` and `carwishlst` are lists:

You would do the following

```
def cars_you_want(cars, carwishlst):
    car_set = [val for val in cars if val in carwishlst]
    return len(car_set)
```

That should do it.

Comment: they are straight from the models of related objects. Do I have to turn them into a list?

Comment: paste your models into the question.

Comment: its just hypothetical, but lets say Grange model has an FK cars = models.ManyToManyField(Cars) Person also has a FK  cars_wishlist = models.ManyToManyField(Cars)

Comment: changed the question to reflect its from a db table and not a list, sorry.

Comment: that will return a queryset which are lists contain the objects so if they are all car objects (which they would have to be in order to compare) this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `Garage.cars` and `Person.carwishlist` are both lists and that the contained cars have a sensible `__eq__` method:

```
numberOfWishedCarsInGarage = len (set (garageX.cars) & set (personX.carwishlist) )
```

Comment: What is 'set"? I have not seen that before, what does it do?

Comment: A set is a collection of unique items. http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset