# Proper way to annotate favorited items

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given this models:

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    favorited = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='FavoritedPieces', blank=True, null=True)

class FavoritedPieces(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    piece = models.ForeignKey(Piece)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I get the list of all Pieces with an extra field, "favorited", as true or false? This depends if the user marked it as favorited.

Example:
I have a list of 10 pieces. The user favorited 3 of them. When I print the list, I need also print if the piece has been favorited by this user or not.

```
List: [ <Piece1: name.. description.. favorited:False>, 
        <Piece2: name.. description.. favorited:False>, 
        <Piece3: name.. description.. favorited:True>, 
      ]
```

I don't want make a new list of items like this question: [How to compare lists and get total matching items count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912949/how-to-compare-lists-and-get-total-matching-items-count)

I want something similar to this: `MyModel.objects.annotate(total_likes=Sum('piece__total_likes'))`

Which is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing something like this:

`pieces = Piece.objects.annotate(favorites_count=Count('FavoritedPieces'))`

And then when you go through your results, you can do:
`if piece.favorites_count > 0:`

I know it's not exactly what you were looking for, but I think it's simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
Piece.objects.extra(select={'was_favorited': '''
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END
    FROM appname_favoritedpieces
        WHERE appname_favoritedpieces.piece_id = appname_piece.id
'''})
```

This will give you an extra field `'was_favorited'`. However, if all you're doing is checking whether or not the Piece was favorited, there are much simpler ways of doing this:

Test the field itself:

```
for p in Piece.objects.all():
    if p.favorited:
        pass  # do something if the Piece was favorited
```

If you really need that boolean, add a property `was_favorited()`:

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def was_favorited(self):
        return true if self.favorited else false


# then you can call this property on Piece objects:
>>> Piece.objects.get(name="No one's favorite").was_favorited
False
```

Comment: I didn't remember to say that the favorited is relative to an user. "I have a list of 10 pieces. The user favorited 3 of them. When I print the list, I need also print if the piece has been favorited by this user or not."

Comment: You would most likely want to use prefetch_related to avoid doing too many queries. ```Pieces.objects.all().prefetch_related('favorited')```